# Есть ли способ, чтобы запретить перемещение курсора в UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, cursor

Я хотел бы,  отключить возможность перемещение курсора и чтобы он всегда был в конце строки и отключить magnifying glass.  Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Курсор в UITextField можно переставлять программно.

Делается так:

Objective C

```
- (void) setCursorToTextfieldEnd: (UITextField*) textfield {
    UITextPosition* end = [textfield endOfDocument];
    [textfield setSelectedTextRange:[textfield textRangeFromPosition:end toPosition:end]];
}
```

Swift:

```swift
func setCursorToTextfieldEnd(_ textfield: UITextField) {
        let end = textfield.endOfDocument
        textfield.selectedTextRange = textfield.textRange(from: end, to: end)
    }
```

Этот метод переставит курсор в конец текста в контроле. Соответсвенно вызываете его откуда вам надо (например из `textFieldDidBeginEditing` или `textFieldShouldReturn`)

С лупой ситуация хуже. В принципе можно запретить лупу через `textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled`: проставлять параметр в NO при `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` и убирать обратно в `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Помимо лупы это еще запретит перемещение курсора в принципе (текст вы сможете продолжать набирать). На мой взгляд, это дикий костыль, дважды подумайте, надо ли вам это.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, но я хочу сделать так чтоб пользователь мог вписывать данные только с клавиатуры с конца строки и отключить ему возможность копировать/вырезать/вставлять. Вот сейчас не могу разобраться с проблемой как выключить основательно лупу, так как к сожалению через лупу можно перенести курсор=(

Comment: Может быть подскажите как отключить курсор и отключить лупу ,был бы очень признателен за помощь?

Comment: Так, а текущий ответ-то вы попробовали использовать? Вторая часть с isUserInteractionEnabled как раз и делает это.

Comment: Пробовал использовать textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = NO;
Получаю ошибку
 No setter method 'setIsUserInteractionEnabled:' for assignment to property No setter method 'setIsUserInteractionEnabled:' for assignment to property

Comment: [textfield setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: спасибо вам огромное огромнейшее просто вы очень меня спасли.

Comment: @D.Rude, если ответ вам помог, нажмите на галку напротив него.

Comment: если зажать пальцем на текстовом поле,то появляется лупа и возможность копировать и перемещать курсор, мб вы знаете как эту лупу выключить?